# How to refresh item in a popup menu in Livecode

Tags: livecode

I have a pop-up menu and items are read from an array and I want to refresh when I press the right mouse button. Also, is there any way to disable/enable the items of the pop-up menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a pop-up menu and give it a name, e.g. "List A". Now create a control with a mouseDown handler or add a mouseDown handler to the card script.

```
on mouseDown theMouseButton
     if theMouseButton is 3 then
         put "One item,Another item,A third item,The last item" into myList
         replace comma with cr in myList
         put myList into btn "List A"
         popup btn "List A"
     end if
end mouseDown
```

Set the script of the pop-up menu button to the following:

```
on menuPick theItem
     switch theItem
          case "One item"
               answer "Congrats"
               break
          default
               beep
               answer "Not implented yet"
               break
     end switch
end menuPick
```

You can disable individual items by preceding them with a parenthesis:

```
put "One item,Another item,(A third item,The last item" into myList
```

This will disable the third item in the menu.

There is no need to use arrays.